# I have created 3 tables which contains parent,child,marks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the Parent Table:

```
Id int(primarykey),
Firstname varchar(50),
Email  varchar(50)
```

In the Child Table:

```
Mid int(primarykey),
Mark1 int,
Mark2 int,
Id int(foreignkey)
```

In the Mark Table:

```
Uid int(primarykey),
Mark3 int,
Id int(foreignkey)
```

I'm using this query:

```
select Id,Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Mark3
from
(select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent 
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child 
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark)t
group by Id,Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Mark3
```

but if i make group by function using id,firstname,mark1,mark2,mark3 and I'm getting results like this

[image]

So I need result to be like this so is that possible to do?

[image]

Comment: Do not use name `id` as foreign key. Normally we use `<tablename>_id` for a foreign key so like parent_id for table child

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected result

Comment: please take a look at this  link(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to improve the question and dont post images

Answer (score 0):

Just replace union with union all.

```
select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent 
union all
select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child 
union all
select Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use UNION, but join:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Firstname, B.MARK1, B.MARK2, C.MARK3
FROM PARENT A
LEFT JOIN CHILD B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN MARK C ON A.ID = C.ID
```

You can find a lot of tutorial on SQL join (eg. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and on SQL UNION (eg. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)